# Where do I put my custom classes and functions in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, function, class, namespaces

I'm trying to build a class with some frequently used functions that I can use from anywhere in my project. I don't know where to build the PHP file with the classes in it or how to recall them... Can anyone help me figure out where all this stuff fits in? THANKS!!!

/App/Http/Helpers/MyClasses.php

```
<?php

class PopularFunctions {
  public function sayhi() {
    echo 'hi';
  }
}

?>
```

/App/Http/Controllers/TasksController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Helpers\MyClasses;

class TasksController extends Controller {

  public function index() {

    $myfunctions = new PopularFunctions();
    $myfunctions->sayhi();

  }

}
```

This returns: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PopularFunctions' not found.

Comment: Please add your folder structure also the path and code of the class you mentioned.

Comment: You should be able to put a new class virtually anywhere in the `app` directory. There's no real restrictions. If you post your code and structure etc. we might be able to help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Laravel comes configured to use the composer [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloader and the root namespace is `App` and is under the `app` folder so as long as you follow the standard and place your files under `app` they should be picked up. If not try `composer dump-autoload` to re-create the autoload file

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Don't put it in the app/Http directory. What if you want to use the class for a console job? Then the Http directory doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 16):

Basically, we could create another directory within `app` directory (`MyCustomStuff` for example), and then `namespace` our files correctly.

I know of two methods.

**1. Global-Function Through Composer**

App/MyCustomStuff/MyGlobalTools.php

```
<?php
function sayhi() {
    echo 'hi';
}
?>
```

then in composer.json in `"autoload": { }` add

```
"files": [
    "app/MyCustomStuff/MyGlobalTools.php"
]
```

so the structure will be

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/MyCustomStuff/MyGlobalTools.php" 
    ]
},
```

after you change the autoload. Then run `composer dump-autoload`

Then in controller, just call the global function (without need to import), like:

```
public function index() {
  $res = sayHi();
}
```

**2. Or Normal Class**

App/MyCustomStuff/MyClass.php

```
<?php
namespace App\MyCustomStuff;
class MyClass {
    function sayhi() {
        echo 'hi';
    }
}

?>
```

In your controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\MyCustomStuff\MyClass;

class TasksController extends Controller {

  public function index() {

    $myfunctions = new MyClass();
    $res = $myfunctions->sayhi();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

create a directory say "Helpers" inside **App/Http**

create one class inside Helpers directory `CustomAvatar.php`

```
<?php

class CustomAvatar{
    public $default_avatar='avatar.png';

    public function make_custom_avatar(){
        // do your operation here
    }
}

?>
```

now if you want to use this class inside your controller :

```
use App\Http\Helpers\CustomAvatar;

 ...

 public function create_user(){

 $customAvatar=new CustomAvatar();
 $defaultAvatar = $customAvatar->default_avatar;

 $user=new User();
 $user->avatar=$defaultAvatar;
 $user->save();

 }
```

Comment: (1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Http\Helpers\CustomAvatar' not found

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel Framework you can only create a controller inside the app\Http\Controller folder. If you want to create a custom class then created inside app folder.

Example:

File: app\FAReports.php

> namespace App;
>
> Class FAReports {
>
> //  DEF //
>
> }

Answer (score -1):

Your original code did not work because you did not namespace your helper class.
It should have been:

`/App/Http/Helpers/MyClasses.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Helpers;  //this was missing in your code

class PopularFunctions {
  public function sayhi() {
    echo 'hi';
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a little change in your controller

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Http\Helpers\MyClasses\PopularFunctions;
    
    class TasksController extends Controller {
     use PopularFunctions;
      public function index() {
    
        $myfunctions = new PopularFunctions();
        $myfunctions->sayhi();
    
      }
    
    }
```